# How to change Jaspersoft Studio edit report version?

Tags: jasper-reports, jaspersoft-studio

In some reason, I need to develop *JasperReports* in low Version 3.5, 
I installed last version *Jaspersoft Studio 5.6*,
so this is problem , I have already changed *Jaspersoft Studio* version : JasperReports 3.5 like below.
[image: from Window -> preferences -> Jaspersoft Studio]

and set project to use workspace settings
[image: right click project -> Properties]

BUT, when I open a new jrxml file , IDE will convert the jasper report to 3.5 format, and when I saved (by ctrl + S or file -> Save) , IDE convert the report to the last Version (V5.6)!!

I tried a lot of way to change this and research lot of doc I can't found the solution, I think it may be a BUG!

Comment: well, you're not crazy, I'm having the same problem. Set it to Version 4.1.1 but it still adds the uuid attributes and other things which aren't supported in that version.